# Xterm:Xt error Can't open display

Tags: linux

I connected to a Linux server using RDP with local user. I run `echo $DISPLAY` and can see `:10.0` as output.

Then I switched to my IDM user which is required to launch the application. When I switched to IDM account there is no display (`echo $DISPLAY` does not give any result). I checked X11 forwarding setting, tried `export DISPLAY` but still getting error as:

```
xset:  unable to open display ""
xset:  unable to open display ""
xset:  unable to open display ""
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

Please advise how to set display for IDM user.

Answer (score 1):

When u change user the xauth settings are gone.
When You are your first user use: `xauth -f ~/.Xauthority list| tail -1`
after switching to another user type: `xauth add <output from previous command>`

Comment: I got below response  "xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/aircrew_delivery/.Xauthority" when run "xauth -f ~/.Xauthority | tail -1" command.

Comment: Can someone help me to resolve this issue please?

Comment: Sorry my bad, try `xauth -f ~/.Xauthority list| tail -1` and after su :  `xauth add <output from previous command>`

Comment: Thanks but it did not help. Getting same response.                                                               xset:  unable to open display ""
xset:  unable to open display ""
xset:  unable to open display ""
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set